# Increase speed of moving recangle around circle in canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, html5-canvas

I am new to canvas and I want to change the speed of moving red rectangle around circle as currently it is moving slowly(60fps) and also I have tried setTimeout but didnt work for me. Can anyone help to move red rectangle with more speed.

```js
 var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

       
       
        var cx=30;
        var cy=30;
        var rectWidth=10;
        var rectHeight=2;
        var rotation= 0;
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        function animate(){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
      ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,10,0,Math.PI*2);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.lineWidth = 5;       
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx,cy);
        ctx.rotate(rotation);
        ctx.strokeStyle= "red";
        ctx.strokeRect(-rectWidth/4+20,-rectHeight/2,rectWidth,rectHeight);
        ctx.restore();

        rotation+=Math.PI/180;
              
        }
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" width="60" height="60"></canvas>
```

Comment: multiply the rotation with a factor perhaps? `rotation+=Math.PI/180 * 10;`

Comment: Thanks Tahir Ahmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `animate` function, you have the angle `rotation` which is passed to [`rotate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) method.

**More the angle to rotate at, more speed you gain.**

Below is your snippet with rectangle moving at higher speed: (Notice that I have changed the value of `rotation`)

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cx=30;
var cy=30;
var rectWidth=10;
var rectHeight=2;
var rotation= 0;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,10,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;       
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(cx,cy);
    ctx.rotate(rotation);
    ctx.strokeStyle= "red";
    ctx.strokeRect(-rectWidth/4+20,-rectHeight/2,rectWidth,rectHeight);
    ctx.restore();
    rotation+=Math.PI/180 * 15;                
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" width="60" height="60"></canvas>
```